# Set environment variables from Cypress to access in react app

Tags: reactjs, cypress

We are using cypress to run automated tests and need to pass an environment variable to detect whether the app is run by cypress or not?

I'm aware that `NODE_ENV` is set automatically by react to development | production but is there any way to add 'integration' to it when running by cypress?

I tried passing a custom env variable `REACT_APP_ENV` while running the command `REACT_APP_ENV=integration npx cypress open --e2e --browser=chrome` and accessing it in App.tsx file with `process.env.REACT_APP_ENV` but got below error:

```
(uncaught exception)ReferenceError: process is not defined
```

Did some search on stackoverflow and the answers mentioned to remove explicit cypress imports from test files but my files aren't importing any.

The only import is done in `cypress.config.json` file to define the config(defineConfig).

It would be really helpful if someone could assist me with this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to checking an environment variable is to check for the `Cypress` property on the `window` object.

The Cypress runner adds this before opening the app.

For example from the [cypress-example-recipes](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master)

**App.jsx**

```js
if (window.Cypress) {
  window.model = model
}
```

---

Another example from a React component test in the main Cypress repo: [cypress/npm/react/cypress/component/advanced/app-action-example
/counter.jsx](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/d0fbd29805e5e8bb0778936a25154fd516fce935/npm/react/cypress/component/advanced/app-action-example/counter.jsx#L10)

```js
import React from 'react'

export class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      count: 0,
    }

    if (window.Cypress) {
      // if this component is mounted from inside Cypress Test Runner
      // then expose the reference to this instance
      // to allow controlling it from tests
      console.log(
        'set window.counter to this component in window',
        window.location.pathname,
      )

      window.counter = this
    } else {
      console.log('running outside Cypress')
    }
  }

  click = () => {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count + 1,
    })
  }

  render () {
    return <p onClick={this.click}>count: {this.state.count}</p>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error of `process` not being found is how environment variables in a React application are embedded at build time, not *runtime*.

The process object is a Node.js feature and doesn't exist in browser environments.
So your command `REACT_APP_ENV=integration npx cypress open --e2e --browser=chrome` is set for the Cypress process but not React app.

You have to build your application with `npm run build`

```
REACT_APP_ENV=integration npm run build
npx cypress open --e2e --browser=chrome
```